# How can execute sed on file by file basis using result of find?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, find

I need to perform a replace on a file by searching for a pattern and the replace is obtained by executing another command that provides the string to use instead as a replacement. However this also needs to be done on each file in the directory. The following syntax does not work as sed has no input file.

```
find . type f -exec sed -i "s/<pattern1>/$(sed -n 's/abcd\(pattern2\)efgh/\1/p')/g" {} \;
```

The idea is the internal sed returns pattern2 for the external sed to use as a replacement for pattern1. However I need to do this on each file in the directory. I am unable to figure out the syntax.

If I use find for the inside sed,

```
find . type f -exec sed -i "s/<pattern1>/$(find . -type f -exec sed -n 's/abcd\(pattern2\)efgh/\1/p' {} \;)/g" {} \;
```

I end with an error as
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unterminated 's' command.

Could I get some help with this?

Comment: I find it hard to understand. :) So for one file, you have to replace 1 pattern with the result of N-x replacements from N files? Is there always one match or at least one match per file for the inner pattern? The list of patterns will be the same for the outer search and replace loop? And files to extract the patterns are the same, as the ones to be modified by them?
 Can you show a bit sample data, 2-3 lines from 3-4 files, before and after modification with simple patterns.

Comment: You can try a loop over the files. Inside the loop you run the sed that gives you pattern2 and apply pattern2 for patern1 in a second independent command.

Comment: Is there a subdirectory involved at all?

Comment: Where do you hope for the inner `sed` to receive its input from?

Comment: @tripleee: that's precisely the issue to specify that

Comment: No, I mean how can we figure out what your code should do?  Code which doesn't do what you want is a terrible way to communicate what you *do* want. What should the inner `sed` statement actually produce, and how?

Comment: @userunknown: Actually it is 1-1 replacement. I did not know how to specify the input to the inner sed. I used find just to illustrate what I had tried but I do need to supply one file at a time as an input to both seds

Comment: @tripleee:, sure, I can explain more. so the inner sed as per sed syntax produces pattern2 as its output that is used as a replacement of pattern1 in the outer sed. What am trying to achieve is the inner sed to take one file at a time from the  'find' command and perform the action and give the pattern to the outer sed which performs its action on the same file. Does that clarify a little?

Comment: No, not really. You want the inner `sed` to modify the input filename and the outer `sed` to replace the original filename in all files with the result? What does "perform the action" mean here?

Comment: No I would like the outer sed to replace only in the input filename. Both inner and outer sed operate on the same file 1 at a time only. Just that they operate on different parts of the same file. That is my objective. For example if 'find' in a directory returns 2 files a and b, then outer sed and inner sed work on a and then outer and inner sed work on b, one at a time.

Comment: I'm curious, whether modifying the file works, meanwhile reading from it. Looks like asking for race conditions or failure to me. If it is only 1:1 replacement, I guess there is a simple solution, too. And whether we need to consider subdirectories. And can we have a stricter filepattern than *, just?

Comment: Sure, I agree, I am looking for that solution. It feels simple yet I am not able to figure out.  Yes for now we can consider only current directory. I am not sure if it is a race condition because is it not guaranteed that the inner sed will execute first in order to execute the outer sed? We can assume that pattern matching expressions of both sed have nothing in common just in case.

Comment: **Be Aware** that calling `sed -i` on a file will change the file time on the system. That is a bit of a pain at times. If there are not a huge number of files, you may look at `grep` before `sed` to make sure the term is in the file before calling `sed -i` (yes it adds a completely additional call of what `sed` can do, but if you have a backup scheme triggered by file times, that can cause issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt, sacrifice briefness for readability. Here is an ad-hoc script, ad-hoc.sh (after discussion in comments and chat):

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
patternInner=$(sed -n -r "s/.*class\s*(.*)\s*:\s*public.*/\1/p" "$file")
if [[  -n "$patternInner" ]]
then
    echo -e "$patternInner matching in $file" >> findsed.log 
    # sed -i "s/void\s*\(test.*\)\s*()/MWTEST($patternInner, \1)/" "$file"
    sed "s/void\s*\(test.*\)\s*()/MWTEST($patternInner, \1)/" "$file"
else
    echo patternInner empty for file $file >&2
fi
```

Modifications: sed-expression from real life. Test for non-empty patternInner.

Some kind of logging is done, if a pattern is found, name of file, pattern which matched.

Don't forget to `chmod a+x ad-hoc.sh`. 
If the tests look valid, you have to activate the line with sed -i instead of the one without -i, to make the changes not just happen on the screen, but in the file.

Usage:

```
for f in *.?pp # would work for a flat directory as well as find.
do
    ./ad-hoc.sh "$f"
done 2> forsed.err
```

or with find, if you insist:

```
find . -type f -name "*.?pp" -exec ./ad-hoc.sh {} ";" 2> findsed.err
```

Of course it could be put into single quotes and executed with

```
... -exec bash -c '....(ad-hoc.sh 
     code 
     here)' {} ";"
```

but I prefer ad-hoc-scripts in such cases. Less masking trouble. Better editable, better testable.

Depending on the variability of $patternInner, masking has to be considered, but maybe it's just characters and numbers, no dollars, asterisk and backslashes, I hope.

Comment: Thanks. But I think my second line could look to indicate that I am doing a nested operation but that is not the case. I am trying to apply an operation using the inner sed to one file and pass the result to the outer sed which does its part on the same file, 1 file at a time. Does your example indicate that? I was getting a feel that you thought I applied the inner sed to all inner files at once. It is actually not the case. It is done on both inner and outer 1 file at a time and the same file over all files returned by find. My issue is to find that syntax

Comment: Okay, I throw this ugliness into the bin, where it belongs. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update! I really appreciate it. The solution above is also similar to yours. I am not sure which to accept. Is it ok if I accept the above as it has little more details about the command itself?

Comment: Accept, whatever you want. It's totally your choice and your criterias.

Comment: I am trying this in a directory but when executing the script I keep getting `sed: can't read ./test.cpp : No such file or directory` test.cpp is a file to parse. The file is indeed in the same place as the script location and it does not contain any special name so am not sure as to why sed cannot read the file. I also saved the file on Linux to make sure no windows characters are present in the file

Comment: Hm. I tried it myself, and had some issues in finding working patterns. :) Which insn't the issue, from the errormessage. Well, the location of the script and target file don't need to match, but the location where you issue the command, and the target file, but I guess they match. Is this the only file which fails/under test? Is it the first command or the second which fails? IMHO either both or none should fail, do you agree?

Comment: Yea I was checking that. I did issue the command from the same location as well. It fails on all files.  I tried the first command in this fashion `for f in $(find . -type f -name ".*cpp"); do ./adhoc.sh "$f";done`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164639/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-avish).

Comment: It's not the best idea in general, to output filenames from find, which is a kind of iterator, just to grab them in a new iterator like *for*. While c++-files undergo restrictions, so that they seldom contain blanks or greater distractions, there is just nothing to win - well, better known syntax, perhaps.

Comment: The issue I had (in our chat as mentioned) regarding being unable to run the commands in the script had to do with the fact that the script contained possibly some control characters as it was created on Windows the first time. I fixed the issue by creating a new file on Linux and putting the commands in there. Accepting this answer as it solved my issue.

Comment: Oh, yes, the always hard to detect issue with EOL in the two systems. If you think of it, you find it immediately. If not, the hints don't help much. Maybe searching for the error message. I'm not forced to switch systems, so I'm not very used to the message/error, is my excuse, while I have seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

If you are assuming that each found file will contain a *single* match for `abcd\(pattern2\)efgh` and you would like to pull out `pattern2` from there and use it as the thing to replace `pattern1` with in the same file, that would be something like what user unknown's original answer looked like.  Here is an attempt at repainting that particular bike shed.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do
    sed -n "s%abcd\\(pattern2\\)efgh%s/<pattern1>/\\1/g%p" "$f" |
        sed -i -f - "$f"; done' _ {} +
```

A few things can be highlighted here.

- We use different separators in the `sed` substitutions so we can unambiguously nest them.

  - If `%` or `/` could occur in the patterns, obviously choose yet another separator.
- Because we cannot nest single quotes, I use doube quotes around the `sed` script. This means all the backslashes have to be doubled to prevent them from being "eaten" by the double quotes.
- We pass `find` results to a simple `sh -c` script.

  - For efficiency, I refactored it to loop over found files so you can avoid spawning a new shell process for each found file. In simpler terms, without the loop, this would be `find ... -exec sh -c 'sed -n "s%foo%s/moo/bar/%p" "$1" | sed -i -f - "$1"' _ {} \;`
- `sed -f -` says to read the script from standard input. This is not portable.

  - On platforms where this doesn't work, try `/dev/stdin` instead of `-` maybe.
  - However, e.g. on MacOS, the default `sed` simply refuses to read a script from standard input. Use a temporary file or some other workaround.

Comment: That is simply head-spinningly compact. Even staring at it for a minute it's still a lot to unpack -- but definitely cool. That's a new trick for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! I am not familiar with every aspect of sed syntax but your solution hopefully will help me understand more. My original command is as now `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do 
    sed -n 's%.*class\s*\(.*\)\s*:\s*public%s/void\s*\(test.*\)()/MWTEST(\1, \2)/g%p' "$f" | 
        sed -f - "$f"; done' _ {} +` but I get syntax error from bash /bin/bash -c: line 0: syntax error near  unexpected token `('        Are the quotes in the command all ok even with nesting?

Comment: You can't nest single quotes like that; `'foo'bar'baz'` contains an unquoted bare token `bar` between two single-quoted strings.

Comment: Yes I understand but in your solution you too have nested quotes correct? the part which has ... `-exec sh -c 'for f; do
    sed -n 's%abcd\(pattern2\)efgh` ... quotes indicating start of sh and start of sed.

Comment: Ouch, yeah, sorry about that. Updated the answer to fix that.